# What is a better approach performance wise

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Lets say I need to fetch some records from the database, and filter them based on an enumeration type property.

- fetch `List<SomeType>`
- filter on `SomeType.Size`
- enumeration `Size { Small, Medium, Large }`

when displaying records, there will be a predefined value for Size filter (ex Medium). In most of the cases, user will select a value from filtered data by predefined value.
There is a possibility that a user could also filter to Large, then filter to Medium, then filter to Large again.

I have different situations with same scenario:

- List contains less than 100 records and 3-5 properties
- List contains 100-500 records and 3-5 properties
- List contains max 2000 records with 3-5 properties

What is my best approach here? Should I have a tab that will contain grid for each enum, or should I have one common enum and always filter, or?

Comment: wpf seems to be a misleading tag. :)

Comment: Why not just query the database for the records the user wants? I don't think with relatively small numbers like this you'll have a problem either way, you could certainly store it all in memory, but usually it's simplest to just ask for what you want, when you want it, and leave the caching to some intermediate layer.

Comment: "Should I have a tab that will contain grid for each enum, or should I have one common enum and always filter, or?" Are you asking about how to technically implement the query, or how to design the UI?  If the latter, this probably isnt the right place for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the filtering right on the database, if those fields are indexed I would suspect having the db filter it would be much faster than filtering with c-sharp after the fact.

Of course you can always cache the filtered database result as to prevent multiple unnescessary database calls.

EDIT: as for storing the information in the database, suppose you had this field setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Tshirts
(
    id int not null identity(1,1),
    name nvarchar(255) not null,
    tshirtsizeid int not null,
    primary key(id)
)

CREATE TABLE TshirtSizes
(
    id int not null, -- not auto-increment
    name nvarchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO TshirtSizes(id, name) VALUES(1, 'Small')
INSERT INTO TshirtSizes(id, name) VALUES(2, 'Medium')
INSERT INTO TshirtSizes(id, name) VALUES(3, 'Large')

ALTER TABLE Tshirts ADD FOREIGN KEY(tshirtsizeid) REFERENCES tshirtsize(id)
```

then in your C#

```
public enum TShirtSizes 
{
    Small = 1,
    Medium = 2,
    Large = 3
}
```

In this example, the table `TshirtSizes` is only used for the reader to know what the magic numbers 1, 2, and 3 mean.  If you don't care about database read-ability you can omit those tables and just have an indexed column.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is usually cheap. Otherwise you could one-time sort all the values and retrieve based on comparison which would be O(n). You could keep track of the positions of things and retrieve faster that way.